# how to remove a Proxy Virus (127.0.0.1:8080) from windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, proxy, network-adapter, proxy-server

it seems that my proxy is always active. If I disable manual proxy configuration it turns on again. I've tried to delete some registry keys but the same keys appear again.

Here is the screenshot of Proxy Settings:

[image: Proxy Settings]

Here is the screenshot of [Internet Option settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndpIM.png). In Connection tab Lan Settings Button is disabled.

Here is the  **regedit** settings i've changed:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
MigrateProxy
ProxyEnable (which is always set to 0)
ProxyHttp1.1 (which is always set to 0)
ProxyOverride (<-loopback>)
ProxyServer (which has the 127.0.0.1:8080 IP & currently I've deleted it)
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you have run a full scan of your computer, and something like Malwarebytes?

Before you can clean up the proxy settings, you must remove the malware that is causing it.

- Start an elevated command prompt
- Run `netstat -abno | findstr LISTENING | findstr :8080` and take a note of the last number on the displayed line. That is the [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) of the process listening on that port.
- Run task manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>) and go to the `Details` tab. Find the process with the corresponding PID.
- Right-click on the process you found and choose "Open file location".
- Still in task manager, make sure the process is selected and click on "End task" to kill it.
- Now delete the file that the process belonged to (explorer should have popped up with the file selected when you pressed "Open file location" earlier.
- Now clean up the proxy settings

Some additional thoughts:

- If the malware is more advanced, it might have a watchdog process that launches the proxy as soon as you kill it. A good way of detecting the watchdog is to use [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see what the parent process is. You can also right-click on the processes and suspend them, so they are running, but unable to do anything.
- The only 99% secure way of cleaning a computer from malware is to reinstall it. (there are some malware that infects the BIOS/UEFI, but that is unlikely here)